# Property 'contentDocument' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: angular, svg, angular7

I am loading an svg file using an `Object` element and, from a TypeScript file, trying to read and modify the svg (like coloring dynamically, creating some svg elements, and appending to the existing svg), but am stuck with the below error:

`Property 'contentDocument' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'`

I am using Angular 7.

**in app.component.html**

```
 <object id="svg1" data="assets/10026_019.svg" type="image/svg+xml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></object>
```

**in app.component.ts**

```
let obj=document.getElementById('svg1');
    let svg2=obj.contentDocument.querySelector("svg");
 let pt = svg2.createSVGPoint();
```

Actually it is showing the error (red line) at `contentDocument`, but when I run the application it is working fine, even though the error is reported.

But when I do `ng build`, it is reporting this problem.

I'm not sure how I can get this error corrected for the build to be successful.

Answer (score 6):

I got it resolved myself by updating the as below. I have mentioned object type as "any" explicitly.

```
let obj: any =document.getElementById('svg1');
    let svg2: any =obj.contentDocument.querySelector("svg");
 let pt = svg2.createSVGPoint();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementById` method returns an object of type `HTMLElement`. Since `HTMLElement` is an interface, it doesn't have some methods or properties that exist on specific elements types. Here, to have access to `contentDocument` property, you should use a *type assertion* to indicate a more specific type for the `obj` variable, namely `HTMLObjectElement`:

```
const obj = document.getElementById('svg1') as HTMLObjectElement;
const svg2 = obj.contentDocument.querySelector('svg');
```

This way you can have correctly typed variables, without the need of using `any`.